# Capybara, не удается найти через assert_selector или assert_text

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Мне нужно проверить наличие на странице текста "Authorize Web Material Staging to use your account". HTML этой страницы:

```
<main role="main">
  <p class="h4">
    Authorize 
    <strong class="text-info">Web Material Staging</strong> 
    to use your account?
  </p>
```

Я использую:

```
assert_selector 'h4', text:'Authorize',
```

но получаю ошибку:

> Capybara::ExpectationNotMet: expected to find visible css "h4" with text "Authorize" but there were no matches 0) Authorization_required Authorize Failure/Error: assert_selector 'h4', text:'Authorize'

Не понимаю, с чем связана ошибка. Помогите разобраться, пожалуйста

Comment: А мне необходимо проверить все текста приведенные на скрине. Не получается( Помогите мне пожалуйста

Comment: Ошибка тонко намекает, что где-то вы забыли авторизоваться